# What is the difference between the v-list-group and v-list-item-group components of vuetify?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to understand components for nesting items of a list but there's no explanation of the use case of v-list-group in the docs, just its API docs. I want to know when I should use each one.

Comment: Do you mean `v-list-item-group`? If you do, Vuetify provides some use case for that on their docs. https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#action-and-item-groups

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Vuetify docs](https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/list-item-groups/#list-item-groups)...

> "The `v-list-item-group` provides the ability to create a group of
> selectable `v-list-items`. The `v-list-item-group` component utilizes
> `v-item-group` at its core to provide a clean interface for interactive
> lists."

Basically it allows for stateful list items, whereas the `v-list` with `v-list-group` do not.